# Float division by zero with pdf2dox

Tags: python, pdf, docx, file-conversion

I am converting multiple pdf files to docx files using the package pdf2docx. Here is the code :

```
def convert_pdf2docx(input_file: str, output_file: str, pages: Tuple = None):
    """Converts pdf to docx"""
    if pages:
        pages = [int(i) for i in list(pages) if i.isnumeric()]

    parse(input_file, output_file, pages=pages)

    summary = {
        "File": input_file, "Pages": str(pages), "Output File": output_file
    }
    # Printing Summary
    print("## Summary ########################################################")
    print("\n".join("{}:{}".format(i, j) for i, j in summary.items()))
    print("###################################################################")
```

I managed to convert most of the pdf files but I get an error for some files during the conversion: [ERROR] float division by zero

Is there a way to ignore error like this during the conversion process ? Is there a way to know which page in the pdf file contains the error so I can filter it before converting the file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do exception handling using try and catch like this

```
   try:
    parse(input_file, output_file, pages=pages)
except SomeSpecificException as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)
```